# Blank page after login in backoffice (SAP commerce hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Good day, new to hybris and currently getting a problem when loading backoffice.. After entering correct credentials in log-in page, backoffice fails to load, just a blank page. This didn't happen before but just after a fresh installation of hyrbis instance on my local computer. I followed all the instructions (I think) to correctly setup an environment for hybris (ant clean all, ant updatesystem, over-write data folder with our data folder, remove backoffice folder in our data folder, build...). Hybris was working fine before using the procedures we used before to install but I don't understand why it isn't working now. The error is something about an xml file java.io.FileNotFoundException under the hybris/data/media/sys_master/backofficeconfiguration/h94/hdd/8853994602526.xml (No such file or directory). I don't know if this file is auto-generated during ant, and the error didn't happen before this current fresh install in my hybris instances I used. Other parts are ok (hac, etc.). I didn't initialize or update in hac though.. as our manual/setup instruction didn't include those steps, only ant clean all and ant updatesystem. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you installed it in the same folder and didn't remove the data folder. hybris build backoffice xml configurations to as a new media and save it on data folder. If the file exist, it isn't update it automatically. I prefer to set reset backkifice config parameters for dev and test environments.

```
backoffice.cockpitng.reset.triggers = start
backoffice.cockpitng.reset.scope = widgets,cockpitConfig
```